# If $AC=BC$ and $A \cap C = B \cap C$ then $A=B$

Tags: group-theory

This is exercise 2.48 from Rotman's "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups".

I'm having trouble proving $B \subset A$ knowing $A,B,C \leq G$, $A \leq B$, $A \cap C = B \cap C$ and $AC=BC$.

I can't use Dedekind's modular law to prove the proposition.

Comment: Please make sure you get the author(s) and title of any books you cite correct in future.

Comment: Does the $\le$ notation denote "is a subgroup of"?

Comment: Yes, it denotes "is a subgroup of".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $b\in B$. Since $1\in C$, we have $b=b1\in BC=AC$ thus $b=ac$ for some $a\in A,\,c\in C$.

Then $c=a^{-1}b\in B$ because $A\le B$.
But it was an element of $C$, hence $c\in B\cap C=A\cap C\le A$, so $b=ac\in A$.

Comment: I was using the property that $|DC||B \cap C| = |D||C|$ and then conclude using D as A and B that $|A|=|B|$ but that only works for finite groups right?

Comment: Yes, but it's a nice proof for the finite case.